# Create silent installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I have .NET application and I create my installer using MS VS 2010 setup template. I want my setup to be in silent mode. for this purpose I used batch file with following context:

```
start setup.exe /quiet
```

and everything is OK, when the target PC already has .NET. But if target PC doesn't have .NET, my setup detects this and starts .NET installation but in Normal mode (not in silent mode).

How can i set up it to be in silent mode.

Comment: Check for .NET install in the batch file and react accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to install the .NET redistributable package quietly. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480242.aspx) for NET2 example. I'm sure that later versions will be similar.

I'm not sure if you can override the Visual Studio boot strapper behaviour for distribution, but you could always write your own batch file to perform the installation.

Comment: txs ChrisBD for reply, and .NET 4.0 can install in silent mode, and i done it succefully. (like: start setupNET4.exe /quiet)

Comment: txs ChrisBD for reply, and .NET 4.0 can install in silent mode, and i done it successfully. in batch file : start setupNET4.exe /quiet

but if i put both commands there

start setupNET4.exe /quiet start mysetup.exe /quiet

then setupNET4.exe always will execute even it exists on PC (in this case installer will perform repair on it) . Is there any way to check if .NET exist , not to start the .net installer

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#detecting_net_framework, you can check for the .NET framework first, then run the setup depending on whether it's been installed.  Kinda getting away from batch files a bit though.